# FormData constructor loses textarea value in Edge

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, microsoft-edge, form-data

I have a textarea:

```
<textarea cols="20" id="testtextbox" name="testtextbox" rows="2">test</textarea>
```

and I POST it by building a FormData object:

```
var newForm = $('<form></form>').append($("#testtextbox"))
var formdata = new FormData(newForm.get(0));

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', '/', true);
xhr.send(formdata);
```

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/7ewnxvgo/3/)

I would expect this to post the value of that one textarea, which works on Chrome and Firefox.
However, on Edge 42.17134 the POSTed request body is:

```
-----------------------------7e2203930476
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="testtextbox"
 
 
-----------------------------7e2203930476--
```

This also works fine in previous versions of Edge.
Am I doing something wrong? As far as I can tell I'm not relying on any deprecated features.

Answer (score 1):

According to your description and code, I suggest that you could check [the official API about formdata](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) and modify your code like the following two ways.

1.use formdata.append to post the value

```
<textarea cols="20" id="testtextbox" name="testtextbox" rows="2">test</textarea>
<script type="text/javascript">
   var formdata = new FormData();
   formdata.append("testtextbox", testtextbox.value);
   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhr.open('POST', '/', true);
   xhr.send(formdata);
</script>
```

the result:[the first way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9MXF.jpg)

2.add a form to the page body

```
<form id="form1" name="form1">
    <textarea cols="20" id="testtextbox" name="testtextbox" rows="2">test</textarea>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var newForm = $("#form1");
        var formdata = new FormData(newForm.get(0)); 

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', '/', true);
        xhr.send(formdata);
    })
</script>
```

the result:[the second way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyZmb.jpg)

Best Regards,

Jenifer

Comment: The problem with 1 is that I need the browser's intelligent parsing of inputs. And I can't just add a form element to the body because I'm collecting several inputs from across the whole page.

Comment: I've tested in several browsers and I do see that Edge may lose the value. I think the code is not wrong.In my opinion, it is specific in Edge that maybe just the version "hide" the value or it is a small bug.