# HTML Textarea not compatible with JavaScript email form (I can work with 220 characters only)

Tags: javascript, html

I have developed the javascript email form, which was discussed here:

[HTML Assigning the checkbox to the form action already defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68318300/html-assigning-the-checkbox-to-the-form-action-already-defined)

and everything works fine, also with jQuery elements.

The problem unfortunately lies in the `textarea`, where the text input seems to be limited for no reason.

According to the word counter here:
https://textool.io/character-counter/
I can work only with 220 characters. If I exceed this limit, the `mailto:` fails.

When I put i.e. one sentence, everything is alright. The problem emerges when I cross some unknown limit of characters. Then the email is not populated.

The full code is here:

https://jsfiddle.net/pq63e4yr/

and the situation depicted here:

[image]

I have "discovered" it by using the lorem ipsum text from here:

https://www.lipsum.com/

and now I am trying to find where the problem might be. I saw, that MS Edge has the similar problem

[FormData constructor loses textarea value in Edge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52736814/formdata-constructor-loses-textarea-value-in-edge)

but it looks like the Chrome too...

The sample of code (apart from the link above) looks as this:

```js
document.getElementById("cfsubmit").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var check = document.getElementById("cfemail");
  var formEl = document.forms.cityfibre_form;
  var formData = new FormData(formEl);

  var jobAddress = formData.get('address');
  var jobPostcode = formData.get('postcode');
  var surveyorName = formData.get('surveyor');
  var feedback = formData.get('feedback');

  var subject = jobAddress + ", " + jobPostcode + " - site survey submission from " + surveyorName;

  var body = 'SURVEYOR:  ' + surveyorName + '\n' +
    'ADDRESS:  ' + jobAddress + ' ;    POSTCODE:  ' + jobPostcode + '\n' +
    'FEEDBACK:  ' + feedback;

  var mailTo = "mailto:mk@gmail.com?subject=" + encodeURI(subject) + "&body=" + encodeURI(body);

  if (check.checked == true) { // If checked then fire
    let link = document.createElement("a");
    link.href = mailTo;
    link.click();
    link.remove();
  }

  mainForm.submit();
});
```

```html
<figure class="feedback">
  <label class="feedtitle" for="Message">Leave 
                      feedback</label>
  <textarea id="opfeedback" name="feedback"></textarea>
  <br>
  <div class="emailreceipt">
    <input type="checkbox" id="cfemail" name="email">
    <label class="checking" for="cfemail">Send me an email 
                                receipt of my responses</label>
  </div>
</figure>
```

and I have no idea what's going on here. Is the `formData.get` attribute limited with characters?

The similar question:

[Getting around mailto / href / url character limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4067391/getting-around-mailto-href-url-character-limit)

says about the 2083 characters limit, since according to this counter: https://textool.io/character-counter/

I can work only for 220 characters. I use the Chrome browser.

Is there some reason behind it?

Comment: URLs are limited in length, and you are creating a `mailto:` URL in order to get the email working. You're probably hitting that limit (depends on the browser).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting around mailto / href / url character limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4067391/getting-around-mailto-href-url-character-limit)

Comment: It somewhat does. However, could be possible at least to send an email with the text cut down? The worst thing is, that once I hit the limitation, email is not sent at all.

Comment: A limit of 2000 characters works on most browsers. This can be easily applied to the <textarea> with the maxlength attribute. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers/417184#417184) answer for more details.

Comment: According the https://textool.io/character-counter/ I am allowed to put 220 characters only. I work in Chrome.

Comment: I have edited my question and rejected the similarity with the one proposed because I can reach 220 characters only.

Comment: @MKR Then maybe that is a limit with the email client?

Comment: This website https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/line-length-in-html-email/#:~:text=The%20998%20character%20limit%20is,a%20line%20for%20robustness%20sake.  says about 998 characters. I am still far away from this value, which makes my situation troublesome.

Comment: What do you mean you are "allowed to put 220 characters only"? I'm using Chrome and I can put as many characters as I want in there.

Comment: When I put more, I am unable to send an email, because it simply doesn't work. 220 characters is the limit

Comment: @MKR Can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: The link is above: https://jsfiddle.net/pq63e4yr/

Comment: You could work around it by doing an AJAX POST to the server with the body and getting the email sent there.

Comment: I don't know how to do this yet

Comment: See [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp) for a simple AJAX intro. But you would need to be able to run server-side scripting e.g. with PHP, Node.JS etc. However this is off topic now, and you would need to do your own research if it is a feasible solution. I'd recommend it if possible since mailto clearly isn't a reliable method. P.S your jsfiddle appears to be broken with many console errors that you might want to fix first.